# RegEx for matching words preceding commas, with exceptions

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

The section of text I'm targeting always begins with “Also there is” and ends with a period. The single names in between the commas is what I'm trying to target (i.e. "randomperson" in the example below. These names will always be different. It gets tricky because there’s other things present that are not single word “names”. Maybe I  can match everything in between the commas ONLY IF it’s a single word/name, but I cant seem to figure that one out. The list of names could be much longer or even shorter, so the expression must be dynamic and not just match a set amount of names.

#### Targeted Text:

```
Also there is a reinforced stone wall, a wooden wall, a stone wall, 
randomperson, a lumbering earth elemental, randomperson, randomperson,
randomperson.
```

(broken over multiple lines for readability)

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please include a snippet of code you have tried so far so we can help further

Comment: You don't have to use a regular expression. You could remove the initial "Also there is" and split on the comma character. Then check each one to see if it's not one of your known entities. If it's not, then it's one of the list of names.

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
sed -r ':a
s/, ([a-zA-Z]*)([,\.])/\n##\1\n\2/
ta
' | sed -n 's/##//gp'
```

Output

```
randomperson
randomperson
randomperson
randomperson
```

Explanation:

Start a loop

```
sed -r ':a
```

Find all occurrences of ', oneword,' or ', oneword.' and replace with ##oneword, or ##oneword. The ## is a magic marker to identify the extracted names later

```
s/, ([a-zA-Z]*)([,\.])/\n##\1\n\2/
```

End loop

```
ta
```

Filter lines based on ## to extract only oneword

```
' | sed -n 's/##//gp'
```

Answer (score 0):

In a program

```
my $text = "Also there is a reinforced stone wall, a wooden wall, a stone wall, "
    . "randomperson, a lumbering earth elemental, randomperson, "
    . "randomperson, randomperson."

my @single_words = 
    grep { split == 1 } 
    split /\s*,|\.|\!|;\s*/, 
        ($text =~ /Also there is (.*)/)[0];
```

The regex on `$text` gets text after that initial phrase, then [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)
returns the list of strings between commas (or other punctuation), and `grep` filters out strings that have more than one word<sup>†</sup>.

On the command line

```
echo "Also there is a reinforced stone wall, a wooden wall,..., randomperson,..."
| perl -wnE'say for 
    grep { split  == 1 } 
    split /\s*,|\.|\!|;\s*/, (/Also there is (.*)/)[0]'
```

The same as above.

Please show us what you have tried for additional explanations and commentary.

---

<sup>†</sup>  A lone `split` uses defaults, `split ' ', $_`, where `' '` is a special pattern that splits on `\s+` and discards leading and trailing space. But in the expression `split == 1` the `split` is in a scalar [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) (imposed by the operator `==` which needs a single value on both sides) and so it returns the number of elements in the list, then compared against `1`.